# Zend Framework 2 Routing dynamically

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2

I am trying myself on the Zend Framework 2 now and have some problems with the routing. I have a navigation like this:

```
Home
Current
    News
    Schedule
Club
    History
    Management
    Referee
    Restaurant
Team
    First
        Table
        Squad
    Second
        Table
        Squad
    Old
        Table
        Squad
    Djunior
        Table
        Squad
    Efjunior
        Table
        Squad
    National
        Table
        Squad
    Utility
        Table
        Squad
Sponsor
About
    Approach
    Contact
    Disclaimer
    Imprint
```

My module.config.php is like this:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            //Literal-Route: Home
            //Controller: IndexController
            //View: index/index.phtml
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Football\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            //Segment-Route: football
            'football' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Football\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'subteam' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '[/:controller[[/first]/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Football\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),  
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Football\Controller\Index' => 'Football\Controller\IndexController',
            'Football\Controller\Current' => 'Football\Controller\CurrentController',
            'Football\Controller\About' => 'Football\Controller\AboutController',
            'Football\Controller\Sponsor' => 'Football\Controller\SponsorController',
            'Football\Controller\Club' => 'Football\Controller\ClubController',
            'Football\Controller\Team' => 'Football\Controller\TeamController',
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            //localhost
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home',
            ),
            //localhost/current
            'current' => array(
                'type'       => 'mvc',
                'order'      => '100',
                'label'      => 'Aktuelles',
                'route'      => 'football',
                'controller' => 'current',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'pages' => array(
                    //localhost/current/news
                    'news' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '100',
                        'label'      => 'Nachrichten',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'current',
                        'action'     => 'news',
                    ),
                    //localhost/current/schedule
                    'schedule' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '200',
                        'label'      => 'Trainingszeiten',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'current',
                        'action'     => 'schedule',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            //localhost/club
            'club' => array(
                'type'       => 'mvc',
                'order'      => '200',
                'label'      => 'Verein',
                'route'      => 'football',
                'controller' => 'club',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'pages' => array(
                //localhost/club/history
                    'history' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '100',
                        'label'      => 'Geschichte',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'club',
                        'action'     => 'history',
                    ),
                    //localhost/club/management
                    'management' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '200',
                        'label'      => 'Vorstand',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'club',
                        'action'     => 'management',
                    ),
                    //localhost/club/referee
                    'referee' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '300',
                        'label'      => 'Schiedsrichter',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'club',
                        'action'     => 'referee',
                    ),
                    //localhost/club/restaurant
                    'restaurant' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '400',
                        'label'      => 'Gaststätte',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'club',
                        'action'     => 'restaurant',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            //localhost/team
            'team' => array(
                'type'       => 'mvc',
                'order'      => '300',
                'label'      => 'Mannschaften',
                'route'      => 'football',
                'controller' => 'team',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'pages' => array(
                //localhost/team/first
                    'first' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '100',
                        'label'      => '1. Herren',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'team',
                        'action'     => 'first',
                        'pages' => array(
                            //localhost/team/first/table
                            'table' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '100',
                                'label'      => 'Tabelle',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'table',
                            ),
                            //localhost/team/first/squad
                            'squad' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '200',
                                'label'      => 'Mannschaftskader',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'squad',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    //localhost/team/second
                    'second' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '200',
                        'label'      => '2. Herren',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'team',
                        'action'     => 'second',
                        'pages' => array(
                            //localhost/team/second/table
                            'table' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '100',
                                'label'      => 'Tabelle',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'table',
                            ),
                            //localhost/team/second/squad
                            'squad' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '200',
                                'label'      => 'Mannschaftskader',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'squad',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    //localhost/team/old
                    'old' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '300',
                        'label'      => 'Alte Herren',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'team',
                        'action'     => 'old',
                        'pages' => array(
                            //localhost/team/old/table
                            'table' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '100',
                                'label'      => 'Tabelle',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'table',
                            ),
                            //localhost/team/old/squad
                            'squad' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '200',
                                'label'      => 'Mannschaftskader',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'squad',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    //localhost/team/djunior
                    'djunior' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '400',
                        'label'      => 'D-Junioren',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'team',
                        'action'     => 'djunior',
                        'pages' => array(
                            //localhost/team/djunior/table
                            'table' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '100',
                                'label'      => 'Tabelle',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'table',
                            ),
                            //localhost/team/djunior/squad
                            'squad' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '200',
                                'label'      => 'Mannschaftskader',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'squad',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    //localhost/team/efjunior
                    'efjunior' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '500',
                        'label'      => 'E/F-Junioren',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'team',
                        'action'     => 'efjunior',
                        'pages' => array(
                            //localhost/team/efjunior/table
                            'table' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '100',
                                'label'      => 'Tabelle',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'table',
                            ),
                            //localhost/team/efjunior/squad
                            'squad' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '200',
                                'label'      => 'Mannschaftskader',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'squad',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    //localhost/team/national/
                    'national' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '600',
                        'label'      => 'Volkssport',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'team',
                        'action'     => 'national',
                        'pages' => array(
                            //localhost/team/national/table
                            'table' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '100',
                                'label'      => 'Tabelle',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'table',
                            ),
                            //localhost/team/national/squad
                            'squad' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '200',
                                'label'      => 'Mannschaftskader',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'squad',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    //localhost/team/utility/
                    'utility' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '700',
                        'label'      => 'Stadtwerke',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'team',
                        'action'     => 'utility',
                        'pages' => array(
                            //localhost/team/utility/table
                            'table' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '100',
                                'label'      => 'Tabelle',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'table',
                            ),
                            //localhost/team/utility/squad
                            'squad' => array(
                                'type'       => 'mvc',
                                'order'      => '200',
                                'label'      => 'Mannschaftskader',
                                'route'      => 'subteam',
                                'controller' => 'team',
                                'action'     => 'squad',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            //localhost/sponsor
            'sponsor' => array(
                'type'       => 'mvc',
                'order'      => '400',
                'label'      => 'Sponsoren',
                'route'      => 'football',
                'controller' => 'sponsor',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ),
            //localhost/about
            'about' => array(
                'type'       => 'mvc',
                'order'      => '500',
                'label'      => 'Über uns',
                'route'      => 'football',
                'controller' => 'about',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'pages' => array(
                    //localhost/about/approach
                    'approach' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '100',
                        'label'      => 'Anfahrt',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'about',
                        'action'     => 'approach',
                    ),
                    //localhost/about/contact
                    'contact' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '200',
                        'label'      => 'Kontakt',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'about',
                        'action'     => 'contact',
                    ),
                    //localhost/about/disclaimer
                    'disclaimer' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '300',
                        'label'      => 'Disclaimer',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'about',
                        'action'     => 'disclaimer',
                    ),
                    //localhost/about/imprint
                    'imprint' => array(
                        'type'       => 'mvc',
                        'order'      => '400',
                        'label'      => 'Impressum',
                        'route'      => 'football',
                        'controller' => 'about',
                        'action'     => 'imprint',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),                                              
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'layout/header'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',
            'layout/sidebar'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/sidebar.phtml',
            'layout/footer'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/footer.phtml',
            'football/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/football/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'            => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'          => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I think my problem is now the subteam-route, because it's static so when I click e.g. on Team->Second->Table the route will be "Team->First->Table". Doesn't matter which team I click this "first" part is always there and I don't know how I make it dynamically. Hope it is understandable for you guys and someone can cleary explain to me, how to make these team routes dynamically. :)

Edit: I updated the module.config.php, you see the whole file now.

AboutController.php

```
namespace Football\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AboutController extends AbstractActionController
{
 public function indexAction()
{
     return new ViewModel();
 }

public function contactAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
 }

public function approachAction()
{
     return new ViewModel();
 }

 public function disclaimerAction()
{
     return new ViewModel();
 }

public function imprintAction()
 {
     return new ViewModel();
 }
```

ClubController.php

```
namespace Football\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ClubController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function historyAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
 }

public function managementAction()
 {
    return new ViewModel();
 }

 public function refereeAction()
 {
    return new ViewModel();
 }

public function restaurantAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

CurrentController.php

```
namespace Football\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class CurrentController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function newsAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function scheduleAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

IndexController.php

```
namespace Football\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function clubAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function contactAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function currentAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function teamAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function sponsorAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function approachAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function imprintAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

SponsorController.php

```
namespace Football\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class SponsorController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
{
    //DatenbankAdapter holen
    $db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');

    return new ViewModel(array('db' => $db));
}
```

TeamController.php

```
namespace Football\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class TeamController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function firstAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function tableAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function squadAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function secondAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function oldAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function djuniorAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function efjuniorAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function nationalAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function utilityAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: No one has an idea/advice/solution for my problem?

Comment: It's  a bit hard for me to follow what you're trying to do. Could you maybe supply a list of your controllers with actions and how they are supposed to correspond to the navigation structure you've provided? The routes you have there are so universal that it's hard to tell what-should-map-where.

Comment: I added the full module.config.php file and my controllers, hope that is what you need. Maybe I shall tell the problem again: I'm trying to reach e.g. this link home->team->second->table, but the when I navigate to the site I will get home->team->first->table. So I get the wrong table from the wrong team. I think the problem is the route "subteam", but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Ok, that's better. But how are the `table` and `squad` sections supposed to work? You only have one of them in `TeamController`, but there are multiple in navigation. So are `/team/first/table/` and `/team/second/table` supposed to dispatch to the same action and there you'd differentiate them somehow?

Comment: Yes I thought that these links will go all to one action and show the table of the clicked team with some if-else, same for the squad. Should I try another way to implement this or what do you think about it? Another question for me is how can I solve this /team/first/table/ and /team/second/table.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is something I think can be solved at least two ways:

- child routes for `table` and `squad` actions
- or add a third, optional, param that would hold `table|squad`
  value, route that to actions for team types and add a condition there. See example below

config:

```
// ...
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Football\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'football' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/:controller[/:action[/:extra]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'extra' => '(squad|table)',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Football\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

As for navigation:

```
// ...
'pages' => array(
    'first' => array(
        'type'       => 'mvc',
        'order'      => '100',
        'label'      => '1. Herren',
        'route'      => 'football',
        'controller' => 'team',
        'action'     => 'first',
        'pages' => array(
            'table' => array(
                'type'       => 'mvc',
                'order'      => '100',
                'label'      => 'Tabelle',
                'route'      => 'football',
                'params' => array(
                    'extra' => 'table',
                ),
                'controller' => 'team',
                'action'     => 'table',
            ),
            'squad' => array(
                'type'       => 'mvc',
                'order'      => '200',
                'label'      => 'Mannschaftskader',
                'route'      => 'football',
                'params' => array(
                    'extra' => 'squad',
                ),
                'controller' => 'team',
                'action'     => 'squad',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it doesn't seem to work. When I want to go to `/team/first/table`  I land on `/team/table/table`. I think something basically is wrong with my routing :/

Comment: I Have one page **add.php** and this page using in both add/edit with the same action then how to set routing dynamically for this page.